# Owl Carousel2 image not displaying full width when using Stretch row and content, Stretch row and content(no padding) in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, owl-carousel-2, wpbakery

I am using Wordpress with a WPBakery page builder and owl Carousel2. I have to display the slider on my page. I have to display the image and text. I have 3 sliders. The code is working perfectly on the localhost without WordPress. No, I have to use this code in WordPress. I am not using any plugin for the slider. I just used text-block and add my code.

```js
$("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  navigation: false,
  pagination: true,
  nav: true,
  singleItem: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 1
    },
    1000: {
      items: 1
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<div id="owl-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="slide_img slider1 blue-overlay">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg">
      <div class="slider-heading">
        <div class="w800 gptw-sectionHeading">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="slide_img slider2 blue-overlay">
      <img src="http://www.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/12/12124/sunset.jpg">
      <div class="slider-heading">
        <div class="w800 gptw-sectionHeading">
          <h2>>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="slide_img slider3 blue-overlay">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-flower-on-dark-tropical-260nw-721703848.jpg">
      <div class="slider-heading">
        <div class="w800 gptw-sectionHeading">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Now the slider is working on the page but the issue is my images not displaying end to end. I am getting output like, two images are displaying. 
[image]

There is no issue with the first two. I am getting the issue in 3rs and 4th option. If I choose 3rd or 4th then I am getting the two images. Ideally, it should display only one image.

Row setting-> Row stretch-> below image

[image]

My expected output is
[image]

Comment: Might be a `css` `width` conflict on the images?  Like maybe the Theme has a `img { width: auto; }` that has more specificity than the img styles from owl2?

Comment: @mikerojas, <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 1140px;"> I am getting 1140 inline width from the plugin

Comment: @mikerojas,  If I click on inspect element to check the code then image displaying properly

Answer (score 0):

```
.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid.slider.vc_row-flex {
    width: 1349px !important;
    max-width: 1349px !important;
}
```

Fixed width and problem solved.

[image]

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.